# Hidden resource files deploying a JavaFX application

Tags: java, deployment, javafx

In a JavaFX application i'm developing I use several icons to style some buttons and view objects. The first icons I used were displayed and packed to the deployed files (.dmg with .app and .exe) successfully, since I had to tell Ant to include the resources folder with the icons.

When I run the project with Eclipse, all the icons and images are displayed right, but when I deploy the project, only two of them (the last two included in the last improvement) are not shown. Why could be this, since I didn't change any folder or configuration?

When I get the deployed .app, I right click on it and clicking "show package contents" I can see that not only these two icons are not packed there in `/Contents/Java/Resources/`, but many others that mysteriously are actually shown in the application. For now I solved this copying all the required icons there, but I can't do this with the .exe generated file, which doesn't show these 2 correct icons.

My application is a music organizer/player called Musicott, [is on github](https://github.com/octaviospain/Musicott) so you can see all the code there. The two icons are the slider thumb used to visualize and move through a track; and the default cover image for tracks that doesn't have one.

In this image you can see the problem better https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aVcz.png

- Code where I set the default cover image at `/com/musicott/view/RootLayoutController.java` lines 503-506
- Code where I set the default cover image in the play queue list at
  `/com/musicott/view/PlayQueueController.java`lines 98-101
- Code where I set the slider thumb icon in
  `/com/musicott/SceneManager.java`lines 245-249

Thanks in advance. I will answer any doubt about the code and the project.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy these images to the file system? Why don't you bundle them into the jar file and retrieve them with `getClass().getResource(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice looking project! So, as James_D pointed you are currently loading your icons with the following code:

```
new Image("file:resources/images/default-cover-icon.png")
new Image("file:resources/images/default-cover-icon.png", 45, 45, true, true));
```

The problem is that when you pack your application the "file" protocol is no longer valid (remember you are sending a URL to the Image constructor). You could send instead an InputStream (you can get one from the current Class), see this sample code:

```
new Image(RootLayoutController.class.getResourceAsStream("images/default-cover-icon.png"));
```

Now, if you use the code exactly like that you will need to make sure (after building the jar) that the "images" folder ends up inside the "com/musicott/view/" folder (since the RootLayoutController class is inside that package), so you will have to add the two extra "com" and "musicott" folders inside your current "resources" folders and move the "images" folder there.. you will probably need to add this in your pom.xml file too (to make sure you export the resources since I think maven will only export by default the "resources" folder located at "src/main/resources"):

```
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
        </resource>
```

**Note** that if you want to keep your current folder structure (without creating the "com/musicott/view" folders inside the "resources" folder) you can change the path in the getResourceAsStream() call to "/images/default-cover-icon.png" (**slash** at the start of the string) to indicate that the images folder will be at the root.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your fix totally worked. I was crazy about this problem. I would appreciate any help/test/contribute with Musicott. Cheers!